# Bullet points with circles. Latex skipping a point

Tags: lists, itemize, circles, bullets

I am trying to have a list with 2 levels and I am finding that it skips the second line of the second level. How can I fix this?

```
\begin{itemize}

\item a
     
    \begin{list}{$\circ$}
         \item a1
         \item a2 % circle skipped here
         \item a3
    \end{list}

\item b

\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you want `\begin{list}{$\circ$}{}`. The `list` environment takes two arguments.

Comment: Thanks @campa that solved my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\begin{itemize}[label=$\circ$]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item a
  \begin{itemize}[label=$\circ$]
         \item a1
         \item a2 % circle skipped here
         \item a3
       \end{itemize}
\item b
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]